# Chillispot and DHCP setup on single server

Tags: networking, centos6, access-point, captive-portal

**Background**

I have a simple network topology consisting of 3 pieces of hardware, a CentOS server, an access point and a 4g modem. The server has 2 LAN ports and the 4g modem and the access point are connected to each.

[image: Network Topology]

**Question**

After reading and watching videos about Chilispot, I am unsure in my setup where my DHCP server would reside. I know it will be on the server box but I am confused if Chilispot provides this or if I need to enable the CentOS in built DHCP server?

As another element I am unsure of, the 4g modem is just a modem and does not contain a router, but it does connect via a LAN port rather than a USB connection. Without a router I am not sure how my server can share the connection to all the devices connected to the AP as a result.

To be clear in my project I have to get everything running on a single computer, and I cannot have anything more. I know from reading that my Radius and Web Server components can all be run locally, which is great.

Answer (score 1):

- You'll need two network cards in the CentOS server and let it act as a router.
- Chilispot doesn't have a built-in DHCP server, IIRC. Install `dhcpd` on the CentOS machine or use the one that might be offered by the access point.
- To my knowledge, Chilispot is dead (last release in 2007 or something).

Comment: What would you suggest instead of chilispot?

Comment: @GrahamSmith: I've no idea, don't need it anymore.